# Node.js and Express Exclude route form JWT middleware

Tags: node.js, express, routes, authorization, jwt

I am trying to exclude JWT authentication for specific routes. I am successfully able to exclude it for some routes but not for some others. I am posting the code below.

I don't need authentication for entering the below-mentioned route and it is working fine.

```
app.post('/api/register*', function(request,response, next){
    console.log("Entered register/user function");
    registerProxy(request, response, next);
});
```

I need authentication for entering the below-mentioned route and it works fine.

```
app.get('/api/users*', protected, function(request, response, next){
    console.log('Entered userinfo function');
    userInformationProxy(request,response,next);
});
```

Below is my "protected" function

```
function protected(request, response, next) {
    console.log('Entered function to strip jwt');
    console.log(request.method, request.url);
    const bearerHeader = request.headers['authorization'];
    if(typeof bearerHeader !== 'undefined'){
        console.log('JWT is present');
        const bearer = bearerHeader.split(' ');
        const bearerToken = bearer[1];
        request.token = bearerToken;
        jwt.verify(request.token, secretKey, function(error, authData){
            if(error){
                response
                    .status(403)
                    .json({'message': 'Forbidden'})
            } else{
                console.log(authData);
                if(request.url.includes(authData.username)){
                    next();
                } else{
                    response
                        .status(403)
                        .json({'message': 'Forbidden'})
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        response
            .status(403)
            .json({'message': 'Forbidden'})
    }};
}
```

But I am facing a problem when I am trying to enter the below-mentioned route:

```
app.get('/api/search', function(request, response, next){
    console.log('Entered search function');
    searchProxy(request, response,next);
});
```

Although I am not protecting this route with the function "protected", it is giving me an error 403 forbidden

Am I doing anything wrong? I am new to Node.js and JWT

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that this route definition:

```
app.get('/api/search', function(request, response, next){
    console.log('Entered search function');
    searchProxy(request, response,next);
});
```

Is BEFORE this one:

```
app.get('/api/users*', protected, function(request, response, next){
    console.log('Entered userinfo function');
    userInformationProxy(request,response,next);
});
```

And, that you send a response from `searchProxy()` and don't call `next()`.  If you send a response and don't call `next()`, then no further routes will be run so there's no way for it to get to your `protected()` middleware.

Comment: The sequence of route definition is fine. Is the problem because I am doing the next() thing wrong?

Comment: @Akshay - You should only call `next()` when you want routing to continue on to other routes.  If you've sent the response and don't want any more routes to run, then don't call `next()` - you're done.  The point of `next()` is to see if any other routes (defined after this one) will match and can run.  In your case, when you get in the route handler for `/api/search`, you do NOT want any other routes to run after it. You've already processed the request and are done.

Comment: Got your point, I corrected the code. But still, I am getting "403" when I enter /api/search

Comment: @Akshay - Then show us the code for `searchProxy()` because that is apparently where the problem is.

Comment: @Akshay - If that's the entire code for `searchProxy()`, then you're getting a 403 from that or you have some other middleware in the chain before you get here that is causing the 403 or that function is calling `next()` when you don't want it to.  Because you're not showing us a cohesive set of code, all we can do is guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169517/discussion-between-akshay-and-jfriend00).